# Controlling components on in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I am struggling controlling my components. I hava a JFrame which contains a JPanel. My components such as JLabel and JTextArea are added to this Panel. So my question is:

How can I control these compontens? I've tried using

`GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
 constraints.gridx = 1;`

But it doesn't seems to work..

Here is my function the initialize my GUI:

```
public void initGUI()
{

    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();  

    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("instantINFO!");
                 frame.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height); 
                 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                 frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); 

    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    weather = new JTextArea(vær, 6, 20);
    weather.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 16));
    weather.setLineWrap(true);
    weather.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    weather.setOpaque(false);
    weather.setEditable(false);

    stedLabel = new JLabel(sted);
    dagLabel = new JLabel(dag);

    panel.add(weather);
    panel.add(stedLabel); 
    panel.add(dagLabel); 

    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

For instance I want the weather label to be in the left upper corner, with a few pixels of margin.

Comment: You discuss 2 components but add 3 in that snippet.  As a result I find neither your snippets nor textual explanations to be effective at describing the GUI you would like to see.  How about some ASCII art (or a drawing) and an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A JPanel uses a FlowLayout by default. And by default components are centered in a row on the panel. If you want the components left aligned then you need to change the flow layout to left align the components. Read the FlowLayout API to see how to do this.

I also suggest you look at the Swing tutorial on [Using Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for working examples.

Answer (score 2):

You should study [Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) to control your components layouts

> For instance I want the weather label to be in the left upper corner,
>   with a few pixels of margin.

To control component location by pixels you can use setLocation() method but then you should set absolute layout or just set your component layout to null which supports x,y location control

code like a

```
aPanel.setLayout(null);
...
aButton.setLocation(10,3);
aPanel.add(aButton);
```

I liked the example of absolute position controlling so I want to share it [example](http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/guidebook/?name=JButton&page=1) watch it to see the conception

Good luck :)

Comment: @camickr Given your link was actually to a document titled "A Visual Guide to Layout Managers" (not "Using.." as stated), these are slightly different links to the same basic tutorial.  I disagree this answer counts as a 'duplicate'.  Gee - I gave that a '+1' before I saw the stuff about 'setLocation'  :(

Comment: @Andrew, you've got to be joking??? It is a duplicate because my link covers this link. The point of the link is to get the poster to read the tutorial no matter what title I use. No wonder this forum gets some many duplicate answer.

Comment: If the poster thought that section should have been highlighted then it should have been added as a comment because the intent of both answers was to read the tutorial for more information. Even the poster realized it was a duplicate because they ammended the answer with the absulute layout suggestion which we both know should never be recommended. I'd give the anwer a double down vote if I could because of that.

Comment: OK.. it was more that the post was just a few minutes after yours (which besides being faster, also included extra information that was valuable).  It seemed unnecessary for the answerer to get a down-vote just because they did not answer at the same swift rate.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson carrefully with that, because that's offended me enough, I'm SWIFT admin :-)

Comment: To the person that provided this answer.  I am reconsidering my earlier decision to up vote this post.  It gets worse with each edit!  Please delete it and put your link as a comment on camickr's post, and for mentioning `null` layouts, wash your mouth out with soap..

Answer (score 1):

as other answers mentioned you should learn Layout Managers. you can have this work done for you by using java IDE GUI designers. [netbeans has a Swing GUI builder](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) that you can use to build your components by drag n drop.

the latest [eclipse Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) release comes now with a nice [WindowBuilder](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/06/21/window-builder-top-indigo-feature-2/) tool.